# php/mysql app security issues?

Tags: php, mysql, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find a web-project “security checklist?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475746/where-can-i-find-a-web-project-security-checklist)

i was just wondering when creating an php/mysql app, whats the main security issues a developer is got to consider, i know this could be a major broad topic, but i just wanted an overview of where to look, and while im wrting and devloping the app, what i need to be aware of thans!! :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VERY broad topic indeed. Just to name the basics, which ideally everyone should be aware of:

- Don't trust any user input. But this I mean sanitize all user input to prevent SQL injection
- Escape all data being outputted on the page appropriately to prevent XSS vulnerabilities and cookie data.
- Do not include files based on user input
- Log all your errors appropriately. Ideally, in an error log.
- Store passwords via a one way hash which incorporate a secure salt.

And read through [Seven habits for writing secure PHP application](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-secure-apps/index.html)s.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [OWASP Top 10](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Top_10), which is a top 10 of the most common flaw in web application. It converts the most common issue that you will come through.

[Web version](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main)
[PDF version](http://owasptop10.googlecode.com/files/OWASP%20Top%2010%20-%202010.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

There's some very useful references to security checklists that you should consider in [this previous response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475746/where-can-i-find-a-web-project-security-checklist) to the same question

Comment: Hmmm. Downvoted for referring to a response (I assume that's why I've been downvoted) that lists some good places to look for security advice... wonder if I'd have been upvoted if I'd cut and pasted all those good references into my response? Or downvoted for plagiarising other people's responses

Comment: good artists copy, great artists steal!! and the latter are stupid!!